# Are there any deity names that end in -us/ur or -is/ir

Tags: gods, sanskrit, prayer

See this for reference:

https://ubcsanskrit.ca/lesson9/nouns-as-is-us.html

I've never com across any and I find it weird.

Comment: Dyaus probably?

Comment: Good point "kākatālīya," but I believe Sanskrit words can't end in "aus" or "au," so I think that Dyaus  is probably already declined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accrording to vishnu-Sahasranama some names of vishnu,

> Lokabandhur, Khanda-Parashur, Sahasraamshur, Veerabaahur, Saadhur, Bhraajishnur, , Shaashvatah-Sthaanur, Babhrur, Jana-Janmaadir, Deeptamoortir, Punya-Keertir, Ambho-nidhir, Nakshatranemir, Mahaabuddhir